# When using valgrind to debug a custom memory allocator, what is the role of the "pool"?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, valgrind

The [Valgrind documentation on debugging custom memory allocators](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools) is based on an abstraction called a "pool."  I'm having a little trouble figuring out how the pool is intended to be used.  My initial guess is that because I have a fairly simple memory allocator (mark-and-sweep garbage collector), I can use just a single "pool."  Perhaps if I had multiple entities managing different memory in different ways, I would use multiple "pools"?

I'd love any guidance on how you think the pool is intended to be used, or how you used the pool in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I am bit late here. I learned that pool is just an reference / anchor address for the valgrind chunk we are allocating. In my case, the pool is quite dynamic (split heap), and whenever a memory heap block is allocated, I marked it as noaccess (as suggested by the documentation), and whenever a new object (valgrind chunk) is allocated, I call the `VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC` with the pool address. This gives valgrind ability to handle multiple pools at a time. We can also directly destroy the pool and valgrind will automatically free the objects in it, and then when we create a new pool valgrind knows that new objects aren't overlapping on previous ones preventing wrong errors.

Here is my code: https://github.com/eclipse/omr/pull/1311 .
There is also a link to documentation, which contains how I understood and used the api.